# Desabilitar verificação de valores mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tenho um sistema rodando em uma VPS que foi feito por mim em localhost (porém em outro computador). Este sistema foi feito em php e se conecta a um banco de dados mysql na propria VPS.
Agora, estou clonando tudo na minha máquina para fazer alguns ajustes, porém, meu banco de dados local não está se comportando da mesma forma.

No banco, existe uma tabela com o campo data_f onde especifico a data de finalização de determinada atividade.
Na VPS, um insert no banco com o valor para data_f = "" não resulta em nenhum erro, porém na minha máquina, retorna um erro.

```
INSERT INTO atividade (nome, data_i, data_f) VALUES ('teste', '2021-04-28 10:00:00', '');

Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '' for column `beto`.`atividade`.`data_f`
```

A coluna aceita campos NULL.

- Já atualizei meu servidor mysql
- Não acho que tenha relação com o PHP, já que, se na minha maquina local, eu usar o banco da VPS, tudo funciona corretamente. De qualquer forma, ambos rodam na versão 7.4

Comment: Já tentou ajustar o modo de operação do banco de dados para [`ALLOW_INVALID_DATES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_allow_invalid_dates)?

Comment: vou ler sobre hoje a noite, mas acho válido acrescentar que não acontece só com datetime, vi acontecer também com uma coluna int na mesma situação, envio '' e retorna erro por nao ser integer.

Answer (score 0):

Lendo no documento enviado pelo Augusto Vasques, verifiquei o que estava configurado na global sql_mode da VPS, e percebi que no meu local haviam duas flags diferentes que estavam aparentemente fazendo esta verificação.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.sql_mode                                                                         |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

SET GLOBAL sql_modes = "NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION";
```